# Replace rows from table that has specific value of multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Let's say I have a table like this called MyTable.

```
| Column A | Column B || Column C | Column D |
| -------- | -------- || -------- | -------- |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   || Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
| Cell 5   | Cell 6   || Cell 7   | Cell 8   |
```

And now I am inserting new row into this table that has format like this:

```
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   || Cell 3   | Cell Something else   |.
```

What I want to do is replace an existing row from MyTable if the row I am inserting has the same value of the first 3 columns of MyTable (column A, column B, column C). As my real table has 250+ columns and
I want to replace rows if they have same value of 5 columns, I don't think INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE is good for this. In my opinion, it would be best to DELETE rows that need to be replaced and just INSERT new ones, but I don't know how to write that query.

I was thinking of INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE but firstly: I don't think I can specify more columns in ON CONFLICT part, and secondly: I think that I would need to specify 250 columns in UPDATE part, so that also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem specifying multiple columns in the `on conflict` clause, you just need a unique constraint on those columns. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BFrokae-)). As far as you having 250 columns (a highly questionable design, but another question altogether) you have no way around it you **must list every column** you want updated.